# how can write a circular Queue class That containts remeoveFirstQ, insertFirstQ, removeEndQ and insertEndQ methods (c++)

Tags: c++, queue

i need (source code) circular Queue class that containts 4 methods with remeoveFirstQ, insertFirstQ, removeEndQ and insertEndQ  (c++)

Comment: what have you tried so far and how do you believe the memory structure should be laid out for it to be circular?

Comment: you need to show us what you did so far so that we can help